# Can't clone from Git on Vagrant box

Tags: git, vagrant, git-clone

> $ git clone git@github.com:package/my-package.git my-project
>
> Cloning into 'myproject'...
>
> ssh: connect to host github.com port 2222: Connection timed out
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I was able to do this until I created a 2nd Vagrant machine. I've since removed that 2nd machine, but I still can't git-clone.

I've tried changing the port to 2300, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

By default, port 2222 is used when connecting *into* a Vagrant box by SSH. Connecting *out*, to GitHub for instance, should be done using the standard SSH port (22).

It's not clear from your question where you've configured Git to use port 2222 for outbound conections, but it should be changed back.